# Removing specific text from a huge file

Tags: unix, sed

I have a messed up file that looks like this

```
@SL2.50Ch00
NNNNnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAATAAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAA

+

fcii[cccff8cffiffcfffffiiiiiiiiiffNflllQllrrruru_uuruuur{~~Z

@SL2.50Ch01
```

I want the file to look like this

```
@SL2.50Ch00
NNNNnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAATAAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAA
@SL2.50Ch01
```

Basically everything from the + till the next header @SL2.5Ch01 has to be deleted. I need to delete the + but keep the @SL2.5Ch01
Also the number of letters has been cut down here by me for the sake of visibility so its actually thousands of letters before the + sign here.

I tried to use grep to first find it and then sed to substitute it with nothing.

Tried:

```
grep '\n\+'
```

Trying to escape the plus with a backslash

```
grep -E '^M\+'
```

doesn't work.

Also `sed` works line by line - how do I ask it to scan an entire file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `awk` is fine, then try this:

```
awk -vp=1 '/^[+]/{p=0} !p && /^@SL2.50/{p=1}p' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ awk -vp=1 '/^[+]/{p=0} !p && /^@SL2.50/{p=1}p' file
@SL2.50Ch00
NNNNnnnnNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAATAAATAATAATAATAATAATAATAA

@SL2.50Ch01
```

Comment: ProLiant-DL580-Gen8:~/Desktop/Z$ awk -vp=1 '/^+/{p=0} !p && /^@SL2.50/{p=1}p' KA.fq
awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (syntax error ^* or ^+)
^+

Comment: @Seigfried, Use this: `awk -vp=1 '/^[+]/{p=0} !p && /^@SL2.50/{p=1}p' file`

Comment: awk -vp=1 '/^\+/{p=0} !p && /^@SL2.50/{p=1}p' KA.fq Just escaped the plus and it worked! Thanks!